# Can I troubleshoot wireless on Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I followed the instructions at this post:

[My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205)

and posted a specific question about intermittent (but consistent) slowness running Ubuntu on a Lenovo Yoga 2 Ideapad:

[Why are wireless networks that work for other people super slow on my Lenovo Yoga?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488127/why-are-wireless-networks-that-work-for-other-people-super-slow-on-my-lenovo-yog)

Which now has a vote to close because it is too broad. I'm stumped. I encouraged someone to buy a Lenovo and install Ubuntu on it, which she did, and now she has the worlds crappiest internet connection and I want to help her make it work. I'm used to using Ask Ubuntu to help me make things work. What is the right way to ask for help troubleshooting a wireless problem in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

[The system itself makes difficult to troubleshoot a problem](https://meta.superuser.com/a/6838/235569): you either provide all the information needed to get an answer or not. There has been cases where those questions work, but they narrow it down to a **single specific issue** and provide more than enough diagnostic information about where **the real problem lies**.

Your question doesn't meet this, is far from "troubleshooting" and akin to something more literal like "my wifi sucks, why?". When you are asking "Why X doesn't work" first remember that "don't work doesn't work". If your wifi connection is slow, you *first have to find the reason* why it's slow and then ask us for a solution to that, but as it reads you have no idea where the problem is otherwise any and every answer will be just guessing where the problem is and probably accentuate the problem which is very bad.

Comment: For anyone that really works with wireless issues all the information that is needed is in the file provided by the script.
The power management is on and it needs turned off so the wireless card will function at full power.
The driver being used usually needs parameters to make it work well.
Also the encryption in the router needs adjusting for maximum efficiency.
The channel should be set to 1 or 11 to cut down on interference.
That is just the basic things I see.
So actually she provided a lot of information that is spot on for anyone that truly now wireless issues.

Comment: @WildMan you are not understanding, I could write 14 different answers about why OP seems to perceive a slow internet connection that ranges from blaming the ISP to the browser cache, passing through interference and channel jamming. That question doesn't discarded all those possibilities and even if you are right you can't say I'm wrong with the information provided by OP. Believe when I tell you, not all the problems are where OP *thinks* they are.

Comment: "Believe when I tell you, not all the problems are where OP thinks they are." That is point as well that is why the information from the script supplies everything needed to narrow down the problem much better then any OP could. But I am not saying you are wrong, but I know all the information was actually supplied just waiting for someone to interpret it. I am not pointing fingers and saying anyone is wrong just a discussion is all.

Comment: @WildMan you are still not understanding that "slow internet" has several solutions depending the specific problem. Lets say that your answer is right in this case, then someone else comes along and try your answer but it doesn't work, he discovers that his channel is overloaded with other networks and changing the channel is the solution, he posts a answer to the question thinking he could help someone else. How can you tell him that his answer is wrong if it answers the question? You can't, because based on OP's information he is right.

Comment: Your script works diagnosing wireless related issues just fine, but "slow internet" is not even wireless specific and your script doesn't account for these problems. Unless OP is able to accurately and systematically discard all the possible reasons, then the question by definition is "too broad" because many possible (and correct) answers are applicable.

Comment: It seems like [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205) should be edited to reflect the above (ie. that the script is useful but AskUbuntu is not an appropriate place to post troubleshooting questions.)

Comment: @Braiam I can live with this, but I actually did rule out most of your pie in the sky answers in my question: this is a consistent problem on multiple wireless networks that work fine for other Ubuntu users. I may have chosen my initial title poorly but there was (and is) quite a bit of relevant information in the question.

Comment: @Amanda why didn't you include that in your question? Is a massive waste of time, just discussing this when you could have done it right in the first place. BTW, did you tried with other browsers?

Comment: @Braiam I did include that in my question. That's why I didn't understand why it was flagged as too broad.